# how to extract rows from csv file in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, extract

In my code, I have tables for each expression. Each table is  in csv format.
for example:
tables.csv

```
+-----+-----+----------------------------+
| a   | b   | a - b > 0                  |
+-----+-----+----------------------------+
|  0  |  0  |             0              |
|  0  |  1  |             0              |
|  1  |  0  |             1              |
|  1  |  1  |             0              |
+-----+-----+----------------------------+
```

```
    t = tx(expr,variables)
    table = str(t)
    with open('tables.csv', 'w') as f: 
         mytable = f.write(table)
    data = pandas.read_csv('tables.csv')
```

now, I want to remove the rows if the last columns value is 0. I want to keep rows if the value is 1 only ?

```
    if (data.iloc[(data['expr'].to_numpy().astype(bool)).all() == 1]):
        print('last col',(data['expr'].to_numpy().astype(bool).all()))
```

Comment: `out = df[df.loc[:, -1].eq(1)]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure for what you need the third column but you can easily select a subset of rows with a condition. Just use the following.

```
df[df.a - df.b > 0]
```

or

```
df.loc[df.a - df.b > 0]
```

Comment: If you think it's pointless to compute the third column, it's also pointless to compute the difference ;) `df[df['a'].gt(df['b'])]`